# Undefined offset: 1 during pagination Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pagination, laravel-5.3

I have setup a query to search tours from the database via search form and applied pagination to the result. Below is the query:

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $days = $request->days;
    $days_explode = explode('|', $days);

    $query= Tour::whereHas('country', function($r) use($request) {
            $r->where('countries.name','=', $request->country);
        })
        ->whereHas('category', function($s) use($request) {
            $s->where('categories.name','=', $request->category);
        }) 
        ->whereHas('country', function($r) use($request) {
            $r->where('countries.name','=', $request->country);
        })
        ->whereBetween('days', [$days_explode[0], $days_explode[1]])   
        ->paginate(1);
    return view('public.tour.list')->withResults($query);
}
```

When form is filled (dropdown) with below data without using `paginate`. Query returns 4 results in view.

`country:Croatia,category:Holiday, days:10|15`

And when I use `paginate()` to get results in multiple page, at first it runs without error But when I click other page like 2,3. It gives error

`Undefined offset: 1`

The url of search page looks like this:

```
http://localhost:8000/trip/search?country=croatia&category=holiday&days=10%7C15
```

URL for page 2 looks like:

```
http://localhost:8000/trip/search?page=2
```

Giving error

```
`Undefined offset: 1`
```

I have used paginate before in laravel but haven't faced problem like this.

Comment: A debug stack trace would be helpful.

Comment: can you call 
http://localhost:8000/trip/search?country=croatia&category=holiday&days=10%7C15&page=2 without errors?

Comment: Yes, it does take me to page 2 with required data.

Comment: Try my answer on pagination. it is dynamic link here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41953914/how-to-create-custom-pagination-link/41954134#41954134

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here, when you go to the next page you don't carry over the query string data so you need to pass this data to your view and you can use the following

```
{{ $data->appends(Request::only('country','categorry','days'))->links() }}
```

This should fix it

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`append()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/pagination#displaying-pagination-results) method to append data to pagination links:

```
{{ $data->appends([
       'country' => 'croatia', 
       'category' => 'holiday',
       'days' => '10%7C15'
   ])->links() }}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/pagination#displaying-pagination-results

Comment: @ZacharyDale yes, use this instead of `{{ $data->links() }}` or `{{ $data->render() }}` Also, change `croatia` to a variable with this value etc.

Comment: So, you are setting static value to keys ? But in my case those data comes from search form's dropdown to be specific.